# Flutter ERR_ACCESS_DENIED in WebView with SDK 30

Tags: android, flutter, webview

My Flutter app was created with the 29 Android SDK and works regularly. I need to move the app to the 30 SDK. In this case, WebView (`webview_flutter 2.1.2`) does not load local html files and throws an exception "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED".

I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559255/err-access-denied-in-webview-in-android-only-with-sdk-30) for same problem for native android case - just use `setAllowFileAccess(true)` for WebView instance, but I don't know how to call this command from Flutter.

Can you give me any help?